# Getting "expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations"

Tags: junit5

I am getting the following error on a autowired field. I have added scan tag in xml file and still does not work.I using spring 5.1.6.RELEASE version

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
</context:component-scan>

Error:

Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'approveTimesheetService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.app.service.ApproveTimesheetService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:391)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:119)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            `enter code here`at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    24-Apr-2019 15:01:13            at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.
```

Class that getting an error

```
 @TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
    @SpringJUnitWebConfig(locations = { "classpath*: service.xml", "classpath*:data.xml" })
    @TestInstance(Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
    public class TestLeaveHourCal_moes18 {

        @Autowired
        private ApproveTimesheetService approveTimesheetService; //error on this
        @Autowired
        private ComparePayUpdates comparePayUpdates;
        @Autowired
        public TestClassSettings testClassSettings; /* variable access type needs public */;
        @Autowired
        @RegisterExtension
        protected CreateTimesheetBeforeTestExecutionCallback beforeTestExecutionCallback; /* can not be private */

        @BeforeAll
        public void setup() throws Exception {

            /* START SETTINGS */
            testClassSettings.setTestIndicator("18");
            testClassSettings.setTitleUnitCode("99");
    }}
```

Service annotation is added to ApproveTimesheetService class.

```
        @Service("approveTimesheetService")
        public class ApproveTimesheetServiceImpl implements ApproveTimesheetService, Serializable  {

            protected static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApproveTimesheetServiceImpl.class);

            protected final static String TS_QUOTE = "'";
        }

Any
```

suggestions?

My servic.xml and data.xml are in web-inf/config folder. Service.xml has the context scan tag. 
My classes are in web-inf/classes folder. I think somehow TestLeaveHourCal_moes18  is unable to find service.xml. May be I am not setting the     @SpringJUnitWebConfig tag correctly. I tried "classpath" and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding the following in pom.xml for maven sure fire plugin configuration session. Looks like it needs a path for where the xml files (service.xml) are.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
                            <additionalClasspathElement>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config</additionalClasspathElement>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```